# Make secure connection with help of a server

Tags: encryption, decryption

I`m curious. If a connection to some server is not secure, can that connection be redirected with one more server in between that will encrypt these files for you? What is that service called?

Basically, connection is made with server that will encrypt your requests and decrypt them for that insecure server, and the response will be encrypted on the way to your computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Congratulations, you have just invented the [Virtual Private Network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_network) or VPN! They are usually used for all your communications and not just for a specific server. In addition, they also hides your real IP from the servers you connect to.

Do note though, that the connection will still be unencrypted between your VPN exit (the server in the middle) and the server you are connecting to.

Comment: Can we do better? (theoretically)

Comment: If the server you want to connect to does not support encryption, no matter what you do the communication will always have to be unencrypted during the last part. More fancy schemes, like Tor, has their benefit, but they can not change that fundamental fact.